# Accessing numerous elements of an iterator

Tags: c++

This is probably going to be rather simple but the solution is currently eluding me. Here is a brief run down of the program.

The program displays and allows the user to shuffle the cards, then display them again on user input in shuffled form. Currently my output comes in a single line, until it forces itself to make a new line from exceeding the window size.

What I need to do is create 4 separate lines of 13 cards, the way I had this in pseudocode is:

```
if(deck[12])
   cout << endl;
```

However I'm having trouble getting it to access the elements of the iterator so that it can end the line after 13 cards have been displayed. Here is my for loop that displays the cards:

```
for (vector<const string*>::const_iterator it=deck.begin(); it!= deck.end(); ++it)
            {
                cout << (*it)->c_str() << ' ';
            }
```

Comment: So, you want to have a newline on every 13 cards? Use a counter perhaps?

Comment: "Accessing numerous elements of an iterator" is a very surreal title for this question.

Answer (score 2):

How about a separate counter?

```
int n = 0;
for (vector<const string*>::const_iterator it=deck.begin(); it!= deck.end(); ++it)
{
    cout << (*it)->c_str() << ' ';
    if (++n == 13)
    {
        n = 0;
        cout << '\n';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this -

```
 if ((it - deck.begin()) % 13 == 0)
 {
     std::cout << "\n";
 }
```

Comment: Although this method did do the trick, I hadn't thought through the fact that the first card would technically be 0, and therefore end the line on the very first card. However, this does implement exactly what I was trying to figure out, so thanks for showing me how to do that.

Comment: This is just an alternative approach to using a counter. jrok's solution is also clean.

Answer (score 0):

You've got 52 cards, and want to show them in 4 lines of 13 cards each. That's easy:

for (int line = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
    for (int card = 0; card < 13; ++card)
        std::cout << *it++);
    std::cout << '\n';
    }

where `it` gets initialized to point to the first card in the deck. Note that the code assumes that the objects stored in the deck can be inserted directly into an ostream. Change `const string*` to `string`; you'll find that your life is much simpler.